# Why did Sir William Stanley support Perkin Warbeck?

Tags: war, 15th-century, tudor-period, war-of-the-roses

It seems odd that the Brother of Lord Thomas Stanley would swap sides so soon after the beginning of Henry VII's reign. I want to ascertain the political, social or economic motivations that could have affected his decision to side with the supposed imposter, rather than support the King he helped usurp the throne in the first place.

Comment: You are asking what some dude who died 400 years ago "thought"? You might want to try occult.stackexchange.com

Comment: On the contrary, I want to ascertain the political, social or economic motivations that could have affected his decision to side with the supposed imposter, rather than support the King he helped usurp the throne int he first place.

Answer (score 1):

William Stanley did not support Warbeck. In fact, he helped put the king on the throne and strongly supported him. Henry had Stanley set up by being falsely accused by a stool pigeon named Robert Clifford who was put up to it by Henry's men. Henry disliked that Stanley was very popular with everyone, and moreover he looked forward to seizing Stanley's estates which were considerable.

In short, Stanley was framed and killed for his money and to eliminate him as a possible rival to the king. The whole story can be found in "Memoirs of the rival houses of York and Lancaster" (1827) by Emma Roberts.

Comment: So it *is* possible to find out what someone thought 400 years ago :)

Comment: No, this is what I said I think, not what William thought.